# How can you prove that $\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = |\lim_{x \to a} f(x)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, absolute-value

How do you prove that  $\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = |\lim_{x \to a} f(x)|$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Randall's answer correctly points out that one can use the continuity of the absolute value function, but it's worth noting that there is a simple direct proof in this case, based on the inequality $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$.

Indeed, assuming that $L=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, we have
$$ ||f(x)|-|L||\leq |f(x)-L|$$
which can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $x$ sufficiently close to $a$.

Comment: ^good/nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute value is a continuous function, so it can pass through limits, assuming both exist.  (They need not:  let $f(x)$ have a jump discontinuity around $a$, where it is $+1$ on the right and $-1$ on the left.)